# how to allot index number using SimhashIndex() to a document dataset?

Tags: python, duplicates, simhash

This code implements Simhash function of four set of data.

```
import re
from simhash import Simhash, SimhashIndex
def get_features(s):
   width = 3
   s = s.lower()
   s = re.sub(r'[^\w]+', '', s)
   return [s[i:i + width] for i in range(max(len(s) - width + 1, 1))]

data = {
1: u'How are you? I Am fine. blar blar blar blar blar Thanks.',
2: u'How are you i am fine. blar blar blar blar blar than',
3: u'This is simhash test.',
 }
objs = [(str(k), Simhash(get_features(v))) for k, v in data.items()]
index = SimhashIndex(objs, k=3)
```

now I have used this code to do indexing of a huge dataset (training dataset: train_data).

```
def get_features(s):
   width = 3
    return [s[i:i + width] for i in range(max(len(s) - width + 1, 1))]

objs = [(str(k), Simhash(get_features(data_train[k]))) for k in range(len(data_train))]
index=SimhashIndex(objs,k=500)
```

but if i put

```
'k=3'
```

it works but for values like

```
'k=500'
```

it goes into never ending loop. Please tell me why this is happening and how do i get index number for my all 'data_train' data.

Answer (score 1):

Without going into your code in detail, k is the maximum hamming distance you wish to allow. k can never be larger than the number of bits in your simhash, and typically it won't be larger than 6 or 7 for most real-world corpuses. Often it must be as small as 2 or 3.

Increasing k will cause drastic increase in CPU time and/or storage required to detect similarities. You won't see the effects of this until your system is under load, with lots of simhashes in your hash tables.

To better understand what k is, see this [explanation of simhash](http://benwhitmore.altervista.org/simhash-and-solving-the-hamming-distance-problem-explained/).

Note also that you will not find similarities between the example texts you've hardcoded. They are very short and hence changing even one word changes too large a proportion of the features. Simhash can only detect similarities when changes are very slight.